# Why won't attatched files created using tcpdf not work except in gmail?

Tags: tcpdf

```
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . strip_tags($content) . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<2;$x++)
    {
        $data = chunk_split($att[$x]);
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/pdf\"};\n" . " name=\"$name[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO the solution is NOT to fix your code.

My advice would be to use one of the numerous very good email libraries that are already available for PHP, such as SwiftMailer or PHPMailer. Encoding email is an extremely tricky task due to all of the nuances of the various email clients/sites and these libraries have already been tested quite thoroughly with pretty much all of them. Existing libraries also include functionality that will help reduce the likelihood that the emails get marked as spam at the destination.

Comment: Awesome! In that case, would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks.